# visualforce page from gmail

Tags: visualforce

we have requirement that we need to add a link  in send email body . Users  send responses upon click this link. when user click this link,system display visualforcepage   and let users to enter data and save them. eventually those data store in salesforce objec.
   my question how can we display visualforce when users click  a link in email body? Please  help me this.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a [Salesforce Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites) that provides a publicly accessible page that your (HTML) email body includes a link to. That way the email recipient does not have to login, though that does mean that you can't control who can enter data - security by obscurity until someone shares the page URL with other. (The URL could include e.g. a single use token to reduce that problem.)